# Best practice for setting up a small fileserver for my group?

Tags: linux, files, best-practices, server-setup

My R&D group are setting up our network and development environment. We have a dedicated 'kitchen sink' server machine, running Using Kubuntu 12.04 LTS as the distribution. which is going to run all sorts of services, one of which will be a file server - not for our source code, of course, but for documents, example files, relevant white papers etc. Users will not be storing their personal files there (i.e. no per-user home directory).

I have all sorts of dilemmata regarding how to set this up, and I'm not sure where to ask or look for a HOWTO/tips/best-practices document:

- Which protocols should I support? SFTP (SSH), SMB, NFS, rsync, others?
- Where should I put the files? `/home/dummygroupuser`? `/var/local/filestore` ? Someplace else? And should this depend on my partitioning scheme?
- Should I configure the services for the relevant protocols in some special way, or is the standard configuration good enough?
- Is there any particular problem with our distribution? I'm used to running headless Debian boxes, and K/Ubuntu is desktop-oriented.
- Anything else you might recommend?

Answer (score 1):

> Which protocols should I support? SFTP (SSH), SMB, NFS, rsync, others?

Use the protocols that the job in hand requires.

> Where should I put the files? /home/dummygroupuser? /var/local/filestore ? Someplace else?

The [FSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) can guide you.

> Should I configure the services for the relevant protocols in some special way, or is the standard configuration good enough?

In general out of the box defaults are a good starting point. Monitor your services and tune them as required.

> Is there any particular problem with our distribution?

*I* wouldn't use a desktop distro as a server and I wouldn't put a desktop on a server. It's more to manage and adds significantly to the attack surface. In general though use a distro you're comfortable with and if it has a 'server' version us that over the desktop version.

> Anything else you might recommend?

Only install packages that you need.

In truth I think you are over thinking this whole thing.